# HTML5 video + TTML subtitle is not displaying subtitle

Tags: javascript, html, video, subtitle, ttml

I am trying to display my Subtitles in video. I have mp4 video and ttml file for the video. When put it in html code, the video is playing but no subtitle is coming[Checked in chrome].
When I checked in IE11 it shows the CC option in the HTML5 video player but there also no subtitle is coming.

Here is what I have tried
http://jsfiddle.net/ilaiya/s49zessy/

```
<video controls autoplay height="400" width="400">
    <source type="video/mp4" src="https://ccdpoc.blob.core.windows.net/asset-b82767bd-bf28-4e03-a2d2-329d6df2b633/Index.mp4?sv=2012-02-12&sr=c&si=107ca7bf-272e-48a9-b824-a48da8b7fe90&sig=o8PPGNFD6k0B7PMwdvZdjEy%2FuRc2r4urqqFd5GJyN2k%3D&st=2014-12-10T10%3A40%3A14Z&se=2016-12-09T10%3A40%3A14Z">

    <track src="https://ccdpoc.blob.core.windows.net/sourceaes34/subtitle.ttml" label="English subtitle" kind="subtitles" srclang="en-us" default>
</video>
```

Answer (score 0):

Chrome does not support TTML out-of-band text tracks. Currently, only WebVTT can be used inside of the  element.

In general, Chromium is trying to remove XML from Blink: https://groups.google.com/a/chromium.org/forum/#!topic/blink-dev/vXuOTK5M0hM.